# How to create a Generic Function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I know it's probably a stupid question, but I can't figure how to create a generic function in Kotlin.

I'm new to Kotlin, but I'm pretty sure it's possible.

I already tried:

```
fun T GetContent(call: ApplicationCall) : T
```

and:

```
fun GetContent<T>(call: ApplicationCall) : T
```

I Tried searching online and in Stack Overflow questions.

I even looked at the documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html)

I think I'm missing something, because it's supposed to be simple!

Anyway, any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the site you quoted:

```
fun <T> singletonList(item: T): List<T> {
    // ...
}
```

It's just the wrong syntax ;)

Comment: Exactly what I was just about to comment - His formatting was **wrong.** That's one upvote for you! :)

Comment: Tnx alot! I feel so stupid! I probably got so frustrated that I missed it.

Comment: **I _too_ had this problem before - I resolved it after looking at the documentation for a couple of hours :D**

Comment: A way to think about it: you have to declare parameters before you use them.  This applies to type parameters as well as value parameters, though the syntax is different, of course.  And yes, the [language documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/) is always a good place to look for anything about the language; most questions are answered there.